# Different styles in one paragraph Apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

> XWPFParagraph bodyParagraph = docxModel.createParagraph(); 
>   bodypart.setalignment (ParagraphAlignment.RIGHT);  XWPFRun
>   paragraphConfig = bodyParagraph.createRun(); 
>   paragraphConfig.setFontSize(25);  paragraphConfig.setText(  "Hello
>   world"  );

Tell me how in one paragraph you can use different styles, for example, you need to write Hello in bold, and emphasize the world?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a `Word` document each text having different format needs to be in its own text-run. [XWPFRun](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFRun.html) provides methods for direct formatting text.

So if the goal is one paragraph containing

**Hello** *World*

then the paragraph needs one text-run for **Hello** followed by one text-run for the space and one text-run for *World*.

Complete example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

public class CreateWordHelloWorld {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  XWPFDocument doc= new XWPFDocument();
  XWPFParagraph paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run;

  //text run for "Hello" bold
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setBold(true);
  run.setFontSize(25);
  run.setText("Hello");
  //text run for space 
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setFontSize(25);
  run.setText(" ");
  //text run for "World" italic
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setFontSize(25);
  run.setItalic(true);
  run.setText("World");

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("WordDocument.docx");
  doc.write(out);
  out.close();
  doc.close();

 }
}
```